# Ruby logical "and" operator

Tags: ruby, operator-keyword

When playing with IRB I came across this:

```
a = -1
b = 1
(a and b) > 0
```

returns `true`, however

```
(false and true) == true
```

returns `false`.

Why does the first statement return `true`? In the 'pickaxe' I read "Both `and` and `&&` evaluate to true only if both operands are true. They evaluate the second operand only if the ﬁrst is true[...]"

This implies -- to me -- that the first statement should return `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should it be false? Both operands `a` and `b` are not false, and even not nil..

<strike>IIRC, in Ruby, **every value** different than false/nil is considered true. Even zero. Hence `0 and 0` is true. -1 and 1 surely too!</strike>

EDIT: aah, I just grasped what you meant. You mean that the first expression `-1 and 1` should return -1? No, that's what OR does!

```
-1 and 1   =>  1
-1 or 1    => -1
```

AND evaluates ALL operand for 'true' result, and reduces checks only if one item is 'false'.
OR evaluates ALL operand for 'false' result, and reduces checks only if one item is 'true'

Comment: Ok! I thought Ruby would check if both a and b are greater than zero. Apparently, my understanding of `true` is false. I will check on that, thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, you're really wonderful.

What caught me (and possibly other Ruby newbs) was this:

    `1 > 0 # => true`
    `-1 < 0 # => true`

so I thought the logical way to test if *both* of these are greater than zero was to use `and`. I now do it like this:

    `(( 1 > 0) and ( -1 > 0)) == true`
which returns `false`, as I would expect. Thus I'm actually comparing two statements, rather than two numbers. I now get that `-1` is always `true` because it's neither `false` nor `nil` Hopefully I'm now on the right track. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Both -1 and 1 are "truthy" values from ruby's point of view. That's why

```
-1 and 1 # => 1
false and true => false
```

> that the first statement should return false

I don't see where you got this from. Aren't you confusing it with OR operator?

```
a = -1
b = 1

a and b # => 1
(a and b) > 0 # => true

a && b # => 1
(a && b) > 0 # => true

a || b # => -1
(a || b) > 0 # => false
```

Comment: I believe he both confused the operators, and also had the '0 is false' from C-class languages

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: and, it turns out, he had wrong idea about what `and` does :)

Answer (score 0):

in ruby, the only time an object is false is if it is false or nil.

```
>> !!nil # false
>> !!false # false
>> !!-1 # true
```

in your syntax, it is impossible to get what you want to say when you try

```
>> (1 and -1) > 0
```

<strike>since `and` should be used to return true or false but what I found interesting is the value returned</strike>

```
>> (1 and -1) # -1
>> (-1 and 1) # 1
```

so having `(b and a) > 0` would return false which is interesting

`(1 and -1)` will return -1 since the `and` operator needs to satisfy all conditions. there's something wrong with me today.

Comment: ah got a little confused. the returned values are correct. I was thinking that the second part of the left hand side will not be evaluated since the first part is already true, but that is the behavior of `or`